# ipset alternative or some kind of smart idea for wildcards

Tags: routing, ipset

Senior programmer here but hate the linux networking limitations which make things difficult compared to all programming languages.

Practically I need to make **policy based routing** that allows specific lan ip addresses to pick specific outgoing interface (let's say eth5).
Even ipset is not powerful enough in my situation. I want to allow all lan ips that first octate is "10" and the last octate is ending up with "9". That would be `10.*.*.??9` or in javascript `if(ip.match("\10\..*\.(\d+9|9)\g")) ...USE eth5`

Does anyone knows some kind of trick to achive that ? That would be probably thounsands of IP CIDR if we have to stick with CIDR, which is insanity.

Thanks

Comment: *ipset* is related to *iptables*, not to policy routing. Anyway *iptables* or *nftables* (or who knows, maybe *tc*) must probably be involved (and probably not *ipset*). But I know additional problems will exist if it's about *locally initiated* traffic rather than *routed* (forwarded) traffic: you should tell what's the goal behind this, with a description of the network layout, not only the implementation you think you can use (risk of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: If somebody reveals how to match those IPs, that would be sufficient enough for me to make it work. ipset works with extensions like 10.0.0.1-10.0.1.30 and translates them to CIDR. Yet again this isn't sufficient in the situation to match "9" in the last octate.
Point me a direction when somebody has done that in linux with iptables or whatever and I will try to cope with it. Please forget about XY problems at this stage.
This is the way it must work with no workarounds

Comment: Actually the 2nd constraint is not playing nice with binary bases. If you can't change your project's constraint so that instead of "ends with 9" it could be: "in hexadecimal ends with 9", sets will be needed.

Comment: @A.B I don't get you. Hexdec 9 = Dec 9 .. Anyway what is your idea with hexadecimal numbers ?
ipsets can't work because there's limit AFAIR of 65k records, while /8 network with my requirement must be breaking this limit.

Comment: That it's easy if your special cases are: 9 , 25, 41, 57, 73... (in hex: 9, 19, 29, 39, 49 ...) but not so easy if they are (decimal) 9, 19, 29, 39, 49 ...

Comment: I don't mind using hex. Please explain your idea in detail. Are you referring for something with ipset or something else ?

Comment: @A.B, hey I have another one interesting if you can help. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/748116/unable-to-block-traffic-with-iptables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't limit my answer to a tiny part of an algorithm because OP is also hitting implementation limits. The answer has to work with them.

---

The routing stack, part of Linux' network stack is limited to handling only [33 CIDR netmasks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#IPv4_CIDR_blocks) equivalent to /32 (/255.255.255.255) till /0 (/0.0.0.0) .

Other parts of the network stack, such as some of the firewall facilities are not so limited. By using a netmask such as 255.0.0.255 one can ignore the 2 middle numbers parts in an IPv4 address. Alas, netmasks, which can easily handle power of two, or remainders of divisions by power of two, can't help with a modulo 10 (remainder of division by 10) and a division by 10 is not available in packet processing. So there are still 25 values between 9 and 249 to check and a list for these values is needed. Alas again, in addition [*ipset* is also constrained to CIDR netmasks](https://manpages.debian.org/ipset/ipset.8#netmask), and [*iptables*' use of *ipset*](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#set) doesn't allow to use a non-constrained netmask along: *ipset* can't be used at all.

Either use ~ 25 *iptables* rules (which isn't that much) or use the much more flexible *nftables* with a [set](https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8#SETS).

### With *iptables*

Use a netmask of 255.0.0.0 only to check the IPv4 address is starting with `10.` and check the 25 possibilities for the last part. It's possible depending on the exact problem to solve that additional restrictions for the incoming interfaces to consider could be added.

```
iptables -t mangle -N specialrouting
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 -j specialrouting
```

To populate the user chain `specialrouting` with the 25 possibilities for example use this *bash* script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

iptables -t mangle -F specialrouting # for idempotence
for i in {9..255..10}; do
    iptables -t mangle -A specialrouting -s 10.0.0.$i/255.0.0.255 -j MARK --set-mark 0xcafe
done
```

In the end, the 2^16 (for the two ignored middle bytes) x 25 = 1638400 possibilities will get a mark.

Had the modulo been 16 (a power of 2), thus filtering the 16 values 9, 25, 41,  57 ... 249 instead of the 25 modulo 10 values then everything above could have been replaced with a single rule because a netmask can handle any modulo that is a power of 2. Here the netmask 255.0.0.15 (0xff00000f) can be used with the single rule below:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 10.0.0.9/255.0.0.15 -j MARK -set-mark 0xcafe
```

### Or instead with *nftables*

With the elements list of the set pre-computed with a script similar to above, the ruleset with the modulo 10 cases would be (to be loaded with `nft -f specialrouting.nft`):

`specialrouting.nft`:

```
table ip specialrouting         # for idempotence
delete table ip specialrouting  # for idempotence

table ip specialrouting {
    set modulo10 {
        type ipv4_addr
        flags constant
        elements = { 10.0.0.9, 10.0.0.19,
                 10.0.0.29, 10.0.0.39,
                 10.0.0.49, 10.0.0.59,
                 10.0.0.69, 10.0.0.79,
                 10.0.0.89, 10.0.0.99,
                 10.0.0.109, 10.0.0.119,
                 10.0.0.129, 10.0.0.139,
                 10.0.0.149, 10.0.0.159,
                 10.0.0.169, 10.0.0.179,
                 10.0.0.189, 10.0.0.199,
                 10.0.0.209, 10.0.0.219,
                 10.0.0.229, 10.0.0.239,
                 10.0.0.249 }
    }

    chain prerouting {
        type filter hook prerouting priority -150; policy accept;
        ip saddr & 255.0.0.255 == @modulo10 meta mark set 0xcafe
    }
}
```

For modulo 16 the single *nftables* rule (without its boiler plate) would have been similar to the single *iptables* rule above:

```
ip saddr & 255.0.0.15 == 10.0.0.9 meta mark set 0xcafe
```

### Using the mark for routing

The mark set on the packet (only during the internal life of this packet in Linux' network stack) can then be used as a message for the routing stack and be matched with a routing rule to use an alternate routing table:

```
ip rule add fwmark 0xcafe lookup 100
```

Followed by routes in table 100, the most important ones including `dev eth5` in them, in addition to including any other involved routes copied from the *main* routing table:

```
ip route add ... dev eth5 table 100
...
```

Return traffic from *eth5* should probably use the same table:

```
ip rule add iif eth5 lookup 100
```

---

### Additional notes

At least when testing, to avoid traffic dropped because of incomplete routes, [SRPF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3704#section-2.2), ie [`rp_filter`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.rst?h=v6.1#n1555), should not be enabled (in case the distribution default enables it):

```
for i in $(sysctl -N -ar 'net\.ipv4\.conf\..*\.rp_filter'); do sysctl -w $i=0; done
```

There are other possibilities when using marks, such as storing the mark in the conntrack entry of the flow, but I can't know what would be needed here without a precise description of the setup. This blog has a few examples: [To Linux and beyond ! Netfilter Connmark](https://home.regit.org/netfilter-en/netfilter-connmark/).

Note that involving a mark to reroute *locally initiated* (or the same *locally terminated*) traffic rather than forwarded/routed traffic hits corner cases (and more for UDP than for TCP), so I didn't even try to address this case.

Comment: Very professional from you and definitely got my answer ! I tweaked some stuff because I use the raw prerouting table and used your iptables solution. But I want to know - that's going to be a lot of marks and matches for every packet out there on lots of nodes.
Do you think that actually connmark would save CPU processing time, because once ip is ending with 9, this IP has to use eth5, no other scenarios.
If so, can you give example this way ? Can ip rule w/ fwmark match connmark ?

Thanks

Comment: If it works like this then you don't need to use connmark. connmark would be *needed* for example in case that's the only "memory" available to know the original incoming interface with even more complex routing. Indeed you can save some tests by using a connmark on the flow if it's present. You were given documentation to do this, just try it (try the examples first)!

Comment: Ah: connmark is usually incompatible with the raw table. Conntrack works *after* the raw table.

Comment: Yes, it already works. I was just curious if connmark would save CPU power in case this turns out to be expensive. So far my tests show 2-3%(which is in the error range) more CPU usage with marks and match for single IP. This percentage is too little to be sufficient but if there are hundreds of IPs with mark and match and if connmark saves plenty of cpu power then I'll be probably forced to use another table. That's why I just wanted to know if connmark expects significant benefit or not. Can't find this in the documentation, especially for cases like mine. What is your recommendation ?

Comment: With raw tables or equivalent (ie: hook priority < -200 : conntrack itself hooks at NF_IP_PRI_CONNTRACK = -200 and raw is at -300) the best use is with nftables: the set is already optimized (ie it's not linear O(n) , but hashed: O(1) with worst also O(n) ). So use nftables, change the current linear algorithm with something else using more user chains to improve it, or use the mangle table for connmark. For the later case if you don't find by yourself you should ask a new question

Comment: "the cpu usage will not depend on the number of addresses. the mark is always part of a packet. When it's not set, it simply has the value 0" , yes, but the matter of fact that there's add/change bytes to a packet from 0 to 0xcafe (in this example) means alternations that need CPU power, as well as the ip rule match does a check on absolutely every packet (don't know if this is somehow relieved in connmark approach) . You're right that this is whole new discussion.
Thank you for everything again.