# Unable to block traffic with iptables

Tags: networking, iptables, gateway

Router1 is gateway for another router(2).
Router1 has set 10.0.0.1/8 lan network to which router2 is attached. 10.0.0.1 is obviously the bridge ip address of lan as well as assigned gateway ip for router2.

Router1 has the following rule that successfully blocks every try from router2 to reach destination different than 10.0.0.1 (router1 ip itself..) , **but unfortunately only if router2 is using the 10.0.0.1 as gateway**.

```
iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING ! -d 10.0.0.1 -j DROP
```

The problem is: If I change the gateway of router2 from 10.0.0.1 to 10.22.22.1
and use dhcp to obtain ip address or manually set 10.22.22.22/24 (for example) - router2 is able to access the internet from router1 !? This is strange for me because the above rule is very clear.

What rule should I apply to block router2 internet, and allow access to gateway only 10.0.0.1/8 ?
(The /8 network is absolutely needed for lan, also I need raw table commands only).

Comment: If the IP changes to 10.22.22.1, your current rule will definitely miss it

Comment: Rewriting a former comment (because I probably told something wrong, but still asking for the same information): I have trouble understanding the setup. You should provide more information on both systems. The output of `ip -br link; bridge link; ip -4 -br a; ip route; ip rule; ip -4 neigh` And in addition for router1: `uname -r` (kernel version), `iptables-save -c` and the result of the command `sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables` (No such file or directory is also one of the possible results).

Comment: @BruceMalaudzi why?  !10.0.0.1 means every other IP address including 10.22.22.1 to be dropped, but this only happens if router2 gateway is 10.0.0.1

Comment: @A.B thanks for your comment but I can't share this information ATM and I think we look for logical explanation why the rule works as expected only if the router2 gateway is 10.0.0.1.
I think it has something to do with the fact that different gateway and mask equals different network. This way I get unexpected internet on router2 but also can't access 10.0.0.1 as it is on different gateway/mask. Opposite logic makes sense that 10.0.0.1/8(router1) can't enforce rules onto 10.22.22.22/24 ? But because 10.22.22.1 is neigh of 10.0.0.1 both of them reach the internet. Is that known to be true?

Comment: I don't understand your setup, so I'll wait you provide the information to understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had concurrent 10.0.0.0/8 network bridged with my other 10.0.0.0/8 network.. So when the Drops were actually happening it was picking up packets from the other network which is different and the router has no way to control it.